# Silverlight binding image to Id in datagrid

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, gridview

Im trying to bind an image to an Id in a grid where I show all my users. Does anybody knows how to do this?
I've got a table User where there is a field called StatusId.

There are 2 kinds of status

Status1: Id:10 | active
Status2: Id:90 | Non-active

When the status is 10 I want to show a green cross, when it's 90 I want to show Red cross.

I'm working with the Mvvm pattern.

Here is my gridcode.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="RadGridView1" ItemsSource="{Binding CovrUsers,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CovrUsersViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="230 0 0 0 " Height="Auto">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="User name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Hourly rate" DataMemberBinding="{Binding HourlyRate}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Rights" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Rights.Description}"  />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Status" DataMemberBinding="{Binding StatusId}" />

            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
        <telerik:RadDataPager x:Name="RadDataPager1" Source="{Binding CovrUsers, ElementName=FirstName}" DisplayMode="All" IsTotalItemCountFixed="True" Margin="230,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="11" />
```

thx for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a ValueConverter to convert your Status value into an image.  Something like this:

```
public class CommentTypeIconConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                int ct = int.Parse(value.ToString());
                if(ct == 10)
                {
                    StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(
                        new Uri("Assets/greencross.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);

                    return bmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(
                    new Uri("Assets/redcross.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);

                    return bmp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(
                    new Uri("Assets/empty.png", UriKind.Relative));
                BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);

                return bmp;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Read this [link](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx) to learn about how to use the value converter on your page.

Comment: And how do I use the converter in my view?

Comment: Hmm it's almost working, but I can't locate my images it seems...

~/Images/active.jpg doesn't work ?

Sr = null ...

Comment: You don't need the ~  I'm using UriKind.Relative in my example, so the path must be relative to the path of your application.

Comment: also, my example is getting the image from a resource, so I have my image in a folder called Assets in my Silverlight project and it's BuildAction property set to "Content"

Comment: jpg should be fine. The silverlight BitmapImage class only supports jpg and png

Comment: It's doesn't error till bmp.SetSource(sr.Stream);
Because sr = still null.

What can be the problem?